# How to mange the re-rendering of components through the app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm fairly new to React and I'm not sure how to handle components refresh through my app.
See the below example:

- I have a component `<ChartPage>` which contains 2 components `<ChartDataList>` and `<Chart>`
- The component `<Chart>` contains a `<ReactECharts>`
- When I uncheck the checkbox on a `<ChartDataList>` I would like to update the chart's options to provoke a re-render of the chart.

What is the best way to handle a case like this?

[image]

Comment: Store the state in the closest parent. In this case ChartPage. When a checkbox is unchecked in ChartDataList pass that change to ChartPage. From ChartPage pass down the state to Chart. Changing the props will trigger a rerender

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using your technique: in ChartPage I created a value 'this.state.randomValue: 0' and I pass this value as props to Chart. Then when I click on the checkbox I pass the event to the parent Chart.js where I change the 'this.setState({randomValue: Math.Random()})', and the component Chart is re-rendered.
I find it interesting that the component is re-rendered even though the props.randomValue is never used.

Answer (score 0):

while the solution you came up with might work - it isn't very efficient and could cause you problems down the road.

## Managing State in React

### useState

Like @Disco mentioned, if you have a state that is shared among multiple child components - you should store the state in the parent. Take a look at this for more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

As an example, you could have something like:

```
const [selectedGraphs, setSelectedGraphs] = useState([]);
```

Where selectedGraphs would be a list of graph id's.
Then you could pass these 2 variables to you ChartDataList.js as well as Chart.js. Don't forget however to listen to a change in props via the useEffect hook.

### Context

If you find yourself working with highly nested data (like ChartPage => Chart => ReactECharts) it might be useful to use the useContext hook. Click here to learn more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

## Managing State in Redux

If you find yourself struggling with how state management works in react, you can try out redux which is ussaly much simpler.